# Java Reflection - calling a a date function

Tags: java, reflection

I am getting a string **"Date.UTC(2013,10,9,0,0,0)"** from a function return. I want to construct a date out of it. something like  **"2013-10-09 00:00:00"**

Can I use reflection to give me a timestamp from the string? 
Or do I have to use a substring and split based on "," and construct the date string?

Comment: Where do you think reflection would come into play here? Parsing the string is the appropriate way to do this.

Comment: Just use parser, I agree with Sotirios, No need of reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with a pattern appropriate for your input format:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("'Date.UTC('yyyy,MM,dd,HH,mm,ss)").parse(str);
```

Here's some test code:

```
String str = "Date.UTC(2013,10,9,0,0,0)";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("'Date.UTC('yyyy,MM,dd,HH,mm,ss)").parse(str);
System.out.println(date);
```

Output:

```
Wed Oct 09 00:00:00 EST 2013
```

Note that `Date` objects carry no formatting information. If you want to print a `Date` in a particular format, create a `DateFormat` for that purpose.

Comment: great.this works. Could you explain why there is single quote ( ' ) in front of Date.UTC and then again before yyyy ?

Comment: @Harpreet Literal characters are escaped by surrounding in single quotes. Technically, you only need to escape those characters that have a special format meaning (eg `t` is a formatting character). Rather than worry which characters of `Date.UTC(` were special, I wrapped the entire leading literal ie `'Date.UTC('`.

Answer (score 0):

To parse a DateTime in any Format, you should have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html, especially at the method `parse()`

The API will serve any further information you need to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, no need for reflection nor string-splitting. Let a date-time formatter do the parsing work for you.

The [answer by Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21743929/642706) is correct technically. But not advisable. The bundled java.util.Date and Calendar are notoriously troublesome and should be avoided. Use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) found in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8).

## Example Code

```
String input =  "Date.UTC(2013,10,9,0,0,0)";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "'Date.UTC('yyyy,MM,dd,HH,mm,ss)" ).withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime( input );

System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTime in India: " + dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ) );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2013-10-09T00:00:00.000Z
dateTime in India: 2013-10-09T05:30:00.000+05:30
```